# date comparisions

Tags: php

I write some code to comapre the dates,here i got the problem is when i enter the date as 2012/mar/23 gives output some times correct,some times wrong.when i enter the date as 2012/03/23 gives output also some times corrct ,sometimes wrong.how can i solve this problem?

```
<?php
    $month = 2;
    $year = 2012;
    $saturday = strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year)));
    echo date('Y/M/d', $saturday);
    $sat1 = strtotime($saturday);
    echo "<br/>";
    $season1 = strtotime ( '+12 week' , $saturday);
    $season2= date ( 'Y/M/d' , $season1 );
    echo $season2;
    $season = strtotime($season1);
    echo "<br/>";
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    echo $date;
    $date1 = strtotime($date);
    echo "<br/>";
    $abc = strtotime ('+1 week' , $season1);
    $abc = date ('Y/M/d', $abc);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $abc;
    $abc1 = strtotime($abc);
    if ($date1 <= $abc1)
    {
        if ($date1 <= $season)
        {
            echo "League already opened";
        }
        else if($date1 > $season)
        {
        echo "league successfully closed";
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "league 1 closed"; 
    }
    if(!isset($POST['submit'])) {
?>
    <form method="post" action=" ">
        <label>enter date in YYYY/MM/DD format</label>
        <input type="text" name="date" size="10" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<?
    }
?>
```

and in output it shows the msg in if condition.before submit the form

Comment: You need to indent your code!

Comment: can anyone tell the solution for the above code?.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', '2012/03/23');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

or like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/M/d', '2012/Mar/23');
echo $date->format('Y/m/d');
```

Comment: very nice - didnt know that about Date - learn something new every day :)   +1

Comment: ok,date problem is solved.what about the if condition msg.why it shows before submitting the form

Comment: ok,date problem is solved,why it shows the if condition msg ,before submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

In Your Code `date('Y/M/d')` format  is main problem. it return empty timestamp for it and due to that it generate incorrect answer. So please use Y/m/d format for strtotime here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

strtotime does not support "Y/M/d"

It will only support "Y/m/d" (note the lower case m)

[Click here for a list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) of formats that strtotime supports.

So you should have a datatype "Y/m/d" for your logic, and just format the display as "Y/M/d" when you want to output to the screen for your users

Comment: i didnt understood what u said? can you do the changes that are necessary in my code...

Comment: No - you can spend 2mins and read my answer again - and then look at your code. You have a format of "Y/M/d", which is "2012/May/10". you cant convert that via strtotext. You can only convert "Y/m/d" which is  "2012/05/10". You can either change your backend code to use only "Y/m/d" - or use the answer posted by Vyautas which will help solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem follow this steps:

1.Don't use Y/M/d format for manipulation. Use only Y-m-d format.

2."first saturday" is calculate from the date given. If given date already is a saturday, the next one is calculated.

3.You are again and again vice verse paying around the `strtotime()` and `date()` function

4.Use Y/M/d format, at representation layer  if you want `strtotime()` for saturday, then why again you are converting it in date format?

In Short, To be more clear, Keep your representation and manipulation separate. This is happening because you are doing both things at a time.